# Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/x-scss

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, ejs

i want to create a website with nodejs but i have a problem with show style in `scss` and `ejs` .

i have a `scss` style in folder `../app/public/scss` and i using this middlware for set static file with express :

```
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.set('views' , path.join(__dirname,'../','resources/views'));
```

and in header i define the style by this way :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/scss/vazir.scss">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/scss/media-queries.scss">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/scss/style.scss">
```

and i using the header by this way in the `register.ejs :`

```
<%- include('./../header.ejs'); %>
```

## Registration

but when i go to the register page it show me this in console :

> Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/x-scss: "http://localhost:3000/scss/vazir.scss".
>
> register:9 Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/x-scss: "http://localhost:3000/scss/media-queries.scss".
>
> register:10 Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/x-scss: "http://localhost:3000/scss/style.scss".

**whats the problem ? how can i sovle this problem ????**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Browsers don't support SCSS. You need to compile it to CSS and serve the CSS files to the browser.

There are various compilers that support it. [SASS](https://sass-lang.com/) is the official one. You might want to find one that integrates with your existing build toolchain.

Comment: i create the goggle chrome not suport the scss ? i run the angular project with scss and this browser and it run good

Comment: Google Chrome is a browser. It does not support SCSS. Your angular project presumably includes a SASS compiler along in its toolchain.